# rosbag error /clock

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ,

I tried to make the rosbag that is refering to tutorial in http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data.

But I could't make the bagfile and the error is the following:

use_sim_time set to true and no clock published . Still waiting for valid time.

I set the use_sim_time true , but I could't be successful.

Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241653/rosbag-error-/clock/) by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-08-13**:
The tutorial says nothing about setting or using the `/use_sim_time` parameter. Why do you think you need to set it?

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2016-08-13**:
I think that I need to set use_sim_time to true,due to the error mssage "use_sim_time set to true".

**Comment by [sasadasd](https://answers.ros.org/users/27743/sasadasd/) on 2016-08-13**:
It is success by restarting the roscore . Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No; the tool is stating that `/use_sim_time` is set; not asking you to set it. I suggest you unset `/use_sim_time` and try the exercise again. (you can also clear all parameters by restarting the roscore)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0